# How to add a trendline with faceted graphs

Tags: r

I made this scatterplot but am having trouble adding a trend line. The message <`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'> keeps coming up but there is no trend line. Maybe i am putting the geom_smooth code in the wrong place? let me know if you guys have any ideas!

[image: Graph]

```
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
df_Number <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:12,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  filter(grepl('Number', names))

df_Duration <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:12,
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  filter(grepl('Duration', names))

plot_Number <- ggplot(df_Number, aes(x=factor(names), y=values)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity") + 
  xlab("Number") + 
  ylab("Value") +
  facet_wrap(~Group) +
  theme_bw()

plot_Duration <- ggplot(df_Duration, aes(x=factor(names), y=values)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity") + 
  xlab("Duration") + 
  ylab("Value") +
  facet_wrap(~Group) +
  theme_bw()
plot_grid(plot_Number, plot_Duration, labels = "AUTO")
```

Comment: Use geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x), which gives a straight regression line, which, to my mind, is what ppl generally refer to as trend line.

Comment: That got rid of the message, <geom_smooth() using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'> - which seems like a step in the right direction - but there is still no trendline

Comment: Your main problem is that your x axis is a non numeric variable. replace it by `Participant` and you will see a regression line.